# UL breaks out of 100% height container

Tags: html, css

UL list items don't seem to obey the parent container 100% width in chrome and firefox.  I tried using `list-style-position:inside;` but that doesn't seem to help:

```
<html style="height: 100%">
<body style="height: 100%">
    <div id="mainContainer" style="background: orange; height: 100%;">

        <div style="background: #1f1f1f; width: 200px; height: 100%;">

            <ul style="list-style-position: inside;">
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Can anyone explain how I can get the ul text in the example inside the orange div container?

Comment: the height:100% is a requirement.  How could you do this without removing height:100% from the parent containers?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `style` attribute of `html` tag.

```html
<html>
<body style="height: 100%">
    <div id="mainContainer" style="background: orange; height: 100%;">

        <div style="background: #1f1f1f; height: 100%; width: 200px;">

            <ul style="list-style-position: inside;">
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
                <li>hello</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need the height:100% of the parent containers.  This is a slimmed down example of a problem i'm having.  I need to float  container beside the black one that takes 100% height

Comment: Added `style height: 100%;` for inner `div` as well. Now i think it works as you want.

Comment: sorry my mistake, the `height: 100%` should be in the original question.  The problem is when set to `height:100%` the parent containers take on the height of the screen.  But the UL element inside is larger than the screen so the window scrolls and you see the UL break out of it's parent

Comment: If you want height of `mainContainer` to be of height of the screen then you can use `height: 100vh` and for inner `div` not to overflow you can use `overflow-y: scroll`. See implementation here - https://jsfiddle.net/VaTz88/ujuzbg2v/